# Ubuntu PHP5/Apache2 - Displaying 500 error instead of error message

Tags: php, apache-2.2, http, php5, httpd.conf

The following script is not outputting error messages to the browser. Instead it results in an HTTP Error 500 response.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

phpinfo();

echo "test" asdf // This should error
?>
```

Ideas? This is a basic php5/apache2 install on ubuntu. httpd.conf is blank, no .htaccess file.

The error.log file displays the error message:

> syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the script has a parse error that prevents it from running, this also prevents it from changing a PHP setting.

Comment: So the solution is to just turn on errors via the ini files. This error is fatal.